# Find specific string in vector column Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, vector, indexing, octave

In my program I need to **ask** the user **a string** (ex: 'C4') and then **obtain the** corresponding **index** to that string on the following **vector**:

labels=['C2';'C#2';'D2';'D#2';'E2';'F2';'F#2';'G2';'G#2';'A2';'A#2';'B2';'C3';'C#3';'D3';'D#3';'E3';'F3';'F#3';'G3';'G#3';'A3';'A#3';'B3';'C4';'C#4';'D4';'D#4';'E4';'F4';'F#4';'G4';'G#4';'A4';'A#4';'B4';'C5';'C#5';'D5';'D#5';'E5';'F5';'F#5';'G5';'G#5';'A5';'A#5';'B5'];

To ask the string is simple, used input and it worked on octave, but to find the index I couldn't make it work. I tried using *find, find(ismember(* and also with a *for* cycle but nothing seems to work.
Appreciate the help 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) (and note `labels` should be a cell array, as the strings have different lengths):

```
labels = {'C2';'C#2';'D2';'D#2';'E2';'F2';'F#2';'G2';'G#2';'A2';'A#2';'B2';'C3';'C#3';'D3';'D#3';'E3';'F3';'F#3';'G3';'G#3';'A3';'A#3';'B3';'C4';'C#4';'D4';'D#4';'E4';'F4';'F#4';'G4';'G#4';'A4';'A#4';'B4';'C5';'C#5';'D5';'D#5';'E5';'F5';'F#5';'G5';'G#5';'A5';'A#5';'B5'};
str = 'C4';
index = find(strcmp(str,labels));
```

You can use [`strcmpi`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) instead of `strcmp` if case is not important.

Comment: It worked!It seems the problem was the []. Thank you very much